# How do we keep a porch with a fiberglass roof cool?

Tags: roof

We have a clear fiberglass roof on our enclosed porch.  We just recently put it in.  Sun pounds in and by afternoon in the summer, it is SO hot in there.  We used to just open the windows and it would cool the house.  The old roof was tinted green and we never had this problem before.  What can we put on the new roof to cool off our home?

Comment: You could look into a film or tint to apply to it.

Comment: Do you think you'll want it to be clear come winter?  If not, I'd say paint it (white).

Comment: You could always go with a [Big-Ass Fan](http://www.bigassfans.com/). Saw these guys at a trade show last year. They were handing out little donkey-shaped stress relievers.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the new roof. Clearly you chose wrong in a transparent untinted roof. It is possible that a stain/dye of some sort (applied to the underside of the roof) might be able to block some sunlight, but I expect that it will bleach out far too quickly from that sunlight.

If replacing the roof is not acceptable, then you might need to add vents to encourage more circulation.